# Convert Objecttype for DML update

Tags: apex, dml, schema

Trying to update a child object from a parent object using the Objecttype returned form a getReferenceTo() but getting errors as Method does not exist or incorrect signature: How can I convert the ObjectType to an sobject?

Would appreciate insight on this.

getRefernceTo is returning the MSTR detail field from the child object as seen in the debug here.

DEBUG|GetReferenceTo for child : (Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c)

DEBUG|GetReferenceTo for child[0] : Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c

```
this.CCRA = (Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c) controller.getRecord();


        public PageReference saveOverride(){
            try{
               Database.update( CCRA );
               this.LOB_NonStdAuto = queryLOB_NonStdAuto(record.Id);
               update LOB_NonStdAuto.Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__r;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ));
                return null;
            }

                //Get reference To NonStdAuto child object:
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c.Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.getDescribe();
                List<Schema.sObjectType> child = dfr.getReferenceTo();
                    System.debug('GetReferenceTo for NonStdAUTO : ' + child );
                    System.debug('Point to Field using GetReferenceTo for NonStdAUTO : ' + child[0] );         

             saveChildren(child[0]);

                PageReference pageRef = null;
                pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.CCRA.Id);
                pageRef.getParameters().put('inline', '0');
                pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;
        }
    //**********************************************************

        public void saveChildren(sObject child ){
            try{
                 Database.update( child );
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                system.debug( 'Error saving child: ' + ex.getMessage() );
            }
        }

    //**********************************************************
    Private CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c queryLOB_NonStdAuto(Id CCRA_ID) {    
        LOB_NonStdAuto = [
            SELECT 
                Id
                ,Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c
            FROM 
                CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c 
            WHERE 
                IsDeleted = false 
                AND 
                Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c = :CCRA_ID 
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1
       ];              
            return LOB_NonStdAuto; }
```

Comment: Error is at saveChildren(child[0]);

Comment: To update an object you need to have queried for it first.

Answer (score 1):

The `sObjectType` is a "token" that represents a "type" of record (e.g. `Account.sObjectType` represents an Account token). Instead, you should query the record you want to update, then you can update the record. The `sObjectType` token is primarily used to (a) determine if an `sObject` is a specific `sObjectType`, (b) create an instance of a specific `sObject` type, and (c) get describe information for the `sObjectType`.

In order to update a record, you need to have an `sObject`, not an `sObjectType`. This is typically done by either creating a new record in memory (e.g. `new Account(...)`) or by querying a record (`sObject record = [select ... from ... where ...]`). Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure how we can help you, but generally speaking, you just need to query the related record.

Comment: Thanks. I may have been mislead on using sobjecttype. I do have a handle on the child object already having established its master detail relationship . If if try to update it the values entered on the Visual Force components page clear out and not saved. I have a previous post that someone(s) put on hold? So it’s getting difficult to provide details in the forum. So I’m trying to keep my examples lite?

Comment: if you have an example that shows the query approach then I can refactor my code above to illustrate my issue.

Comment: @rickmac https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm 

getSObject(fieldName) method

Comment: @rickmac If you already have the record, you can update the record. I'm guessing something like this: `update record.Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__r;`

Comment: Adopted updating the child record in code above. However, when executing the saveOverride() the fields on the component object are being cleared and not saved.  @sfdcfox